# Refactoring the "view" code

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

My "view" code has an obvious repetition in its code. Is there any way of refactoring the "return" code?

```
def form_contractor_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContractorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index_view')
        else:
            return render_to_response(
                'form_contractor.html',
                {'form': form},
                context_instance=RequestContext(request),
            )
    else:
        form = ContractorForm()
        return render_to_response(
           'form_contractor.html',
           {'form': form},
           context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        )
```

Comment: I would very much recommend you to consider class-based views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the first else at all. Move the final render back an indent, and that will catch the else case. Note that this is the pattern explicitly described in the documentation.

Also, use `render` instead of `render_to_response`.

```
def form_contractor_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContractorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index_view')
    else:
        form = ContractorForm()
    return render(
       request,
       'form_contractor.html',
       {'form': form},
    )
```

Comment: When the form is not valid, Django keeps producing the error saying that HttpResponse object is none. Therefore, to circumvent that error, I included the first "else". With your suggestion, invalid forms will not be redirected. Is there any way around that?

Comment: No, that won't happen as long as you follow this pattern precisely: as I mentioned, the final `return` line must not be indented.

Answer (score 0):

I will give my try:

```
def form_contractor_view(request):
    form = ContractorForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse('index_view')) # <-- you forgot reverse() here
    return render(
        request,
        'form_contractor.html',
        {'form': form}
    )
```

I replaced `render_to_response` with `render` which does the same thing - you just type less... try to be lazy ;)

I think, this works. not tested though. If request is not done in POST, then `is_valid()` returns `False` returning the `form` as `None` back again which makes sense. and for the case where the request is done in POST and invalid values in it, then `else` kicks in and returns the form with error messages... I think, this works.. please test

Comment: Re: 'you forgot reverse()' - you don't need to call `reverse` first when using the `redirect` shortcut, it will reverse the URL for you!

Comment: @Alasdair you mean `redirect('index_view')` will do the same thing?

Comment: @Alasdair you are right: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L42-L49  thanks for the trick